# Root not working for admin pannel in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-status-code-404

I am tring to give 2 roots one for admin and other for user.
To access the admin pannel http://localhost:3000/admin
To access to user page http://localhost:3000.
But the problem is when an option is selected from the menu of admin pannel it will not take to that page , and shows a 404 error.[if i click option which have an href add-faq it must show like http://localhost:3000/admin/add-faq. but it is showing http://localhost:3000/add-faq  and giving 404 error]
But the user page had no problems.
I am using node js,Express,Hbs.
All files are named properly and no files missing..
If the http://localhost:3000/admin/add-faq is manually given the stylesheets are not loading (404)

GITHUB :https://github.com/bimalboby/clevercode
PLEASE HELP AND THANKS IN ADVANCE

**My App.js file:**

````
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var userRouter = require('./routes/user');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars')

var app = express();
var db=require('./config/connection')

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.engine('hbs',hbs({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutDir:__dirname+'/views/layouts',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials'}))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
db.connect((err)=>{
  if(err) console.log('connection failed'+err);
  else console.log('connected to database');
})
app.use('/', userRouter);
app.use('/admin',adminRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;```

**My admin.js:**

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('adminintro',{admin:true})
  
  });
router.get('/add-prices', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('faqadmin',{admin:true})
  
  });
router.get('/add-faq',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('faqadmin',{admin:true})
   })
 
 
module.exports = router;

**my user.js:**

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index',{admin:false,indexpage:true});
});

router.get('/faq',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('faq',{indexpage:true})
});
router.get('/web-design-pricing',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('price',{indexpage:true})
});
router.get('/e-commerce-pricing',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('price',{indexpage:true})
});
router.get('/seo-pricing',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('price',{indexpage:true})
});


module.exports = router;
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the complete end point like below in **/views/partials/admin-header.hbs** file like below,

```
<li><a href="/admin/add-faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

Your user routes are with the endpoint '/' in server.js.So its working,where as admin need to be linked like /admin/add-faq

Comment: thanks..it worked but the style sheets are not loading...

Comment: In app.js file[Line no 24] where views folder has been set as static. There set 'public' to '/public'.Hope it helps